# Redefine QPainter options when redrawing QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I want to redefine the QPainter before drawing earch QGraphicsItem in a QGraphics scene.

```
void GraphicsScene::drawItems( QPainter * painter, int nbItem, QGraphicsItem *[] items, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem[] options, QWidget * widget = NULL )
```

Is now obsolete, what's the "new" method ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QGraphicsScene isn't in charge of the painter... it is in charge of the storage and retrieval of the items.  The QGraphicsView is in charge of the painter and transformation of the view.

If you want to set render hints to modify the QPainter behavior, you can do that from the view using [QGraphicsView::setRenderHint](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#setRenderHint).

If you just want to do a single render to another special QPainter engine, the documentation shows an example for it to a printer [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html#printing).

Here is link to the docs on [QGraphicsView](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html).